# Multiple Images for one target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

I am working with Unity 2017.4, Vuforia and the Hololens.

I have to align a virtual model with the physical equivalent of it. One method to do this is with a Vuforia ImageTarget. The model is ~1m big. In the middle, where i place the ImageTarget, it works very well but at the edges of the model the deviation is getting too big.

Is it possible to use multiple images for one model? As in one image on the left edge as an anchor point and one image on the right as an anchor point.

I don't have any code to show since this is a question about the concept.

Comment: Could you use a [Multi-target](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Multi-Target-Guide.html) instead of an Image-target?  Might be appropriate if the physical object is a nice regular shape.

Comment: @Jethro Is it possible to use a Multi-Target as something else than a cube? Because I've seen this but couldn't get it in anything else than cuboid configuration. And for the regular shape: my targets would be all in the same plane.

Comment: If I understood u right, its not possible what ur asking. What u ask is not for an multipleTarget. You are asking if there is any option to set several image target as anchors, so the spawning model will be more accurate. How big is your imageTarget and has it a good rating?

Comment: @Perazim It has a rating of 5 stars and is ~ 10x10 cm big.

Comment: Ok I read some documentary. Although you can't use multiple objects as targets, the suggestion from @Jethro is currently the best solution. The multipleTarget provides 6 sides. The tracker knows the relation of the sides to each other, so it might have a better accuracy

Comment: @Perazim did you figure out how to change the geometrical configuration of these 6 sides? I can only get them as a cube and don't see any way of changing this in Unity.

Comment: why would u change them in unity? Creating the cube on dev.Vudoria in the database u set the size right? I never used the cuboid/cylinder but I know for example using the normal imageTarget you can change the size afterwards in unity (in the inspector/component).

Comment: @Perazim because I don't need a cube configuration of the targets. What I need are 3-4 Target points on the edges of a plane, all targets are in the same plane and not in a cube configuration.

Comment: I think we need some clarification in the question.  I have added an answer, but if they doesn't help then please update with some specifics: what does the physical room look like? What digital items do you want to align?  What have you tried, and what problems did you come against?  That'll help keep the question specific and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to align a virtual model with the physical equivalent of it.

A Vuforia [model-target](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/features/objects/model-targets.html) allows you to align 3D virtual models to a matching physical 3D model.

> Is it possible to use multiple images for one model?

Yes, this is possible using Multi-targets. There are examples for cubes, but you can [configure multi-targets](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Solution/How-To-Modify-the-Dataset-Configuration-XML-File-Outside-the-Target-Manager.html#how-to-modify-multi-target) for any regular shape made of flat planes.

> What I need are 3-4 Target points on the edges of a plane

Multi-targets can include coplanar image-targets, and can give better performance than four individually tracked image-targets averaged together.  However, the most reliable approach is to have one large image target which covers the entire area.

Comment: That's it thank you!! I didn't know/realize that you can edit the .xml file and with it the geometric configuration of the multi-target.